# Why not send telegrams request to webhook?

Tags: webhooks, telegram-bot

I create a new bot using BotFather.
Next, I use the following package https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot

Successfully established address webhook https://tg.fryazino.net/hook.php

Sends a message to the bot - webhook no answer to no.
The apache logs except my IP others do not.

As far as I understood from the documents and other sources, following the appointment of webHook, all he has to send messages to this address. Why is this not?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question for NGINX and node.js but the cause was my SSL certificate. You can check your certificate with an online SSL checker like this: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html which also helps to solve the problem if there is any.

Also check this out: [Why telegram does not send the updates after setting webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561246/why-telegram-does-not-send-the-updates-after-setting-webhook)