# Why doesn't telegram send the updates after setting the webhook?

Tags: node.js, curl, webhooks, telegram-bot

I can get the updates with Telegram getUpdates API, while after setting webhook with a valid SSL certificate or self-signed certificate it says:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

But it does not send any updates to my webhook link (I checked the Nginx and node.js access log files), I tried a lot of curl commands for setWebhook API with and without certificate, but still no result:

```
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook -d url='https://www.example.tech/<TOKEN>/webhook' jq .

curl -F "url=https://www.example.tech/<TOKEN>/webhook" -F "certificate=@./www_example_tech.crt" https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe problem in your certificate. Could you check your certificate in any SSL online checker? Is it ok?

For example in this one https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Also do you see the request in access.log if call webhook url directly?

Comment: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/List/Index/37 which said I should bundle all of their certificates for NGINX: `CAT DOMAIN_COM.CRT DOMAIN_COM.CA-BUNDLE > SSL-BUNDLE.CRT`